# How to read file permission bits using only the open and read system calls?

Tags: c, permissions, system-calls

I can examine a file's permission bits using the `stat()` system call, which returns a struct, which contains a field that in turn contains the file type and mode. Is there a way to do the same using nothing but the `open` and `read` syscalls? I.e. by analyzing each bit? For example the following code reads a file (the first four bytes) and determines whether it's an ELF file or not ..

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("main", O_RDONLY);

    char *buf = malloc(sizeof (char) * 4);

    read (fd, buf, 4);

    if (strcmp(buf, "ELF"))
        printf("It is an ELF file.\n");
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a similar way to read a file to extract the information bit-by-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File permissions are not part of the file's contents but part of its directory entry, therefore you can't read the permissions using `open` or `read` on the file.

Using `stat` is the proper way to do this.

Comment: I want to inspect the bits directly, i.e. if permissions are part of the Dir entry, then isn't there a way to read that directly? Any helpful resources will be helpful, I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: @debdut You might be able to if you attempted to read the directory as a file, but you'd get the same values you'd get from `stat`, and the process would be file system specific.  Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Inspecting it that way helps me in understanding the concept. It is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you mentioned in another comment that you're doing this for learning purposes only. Anyone else reading this for production work...DONT. It'll be non-portable! You probably just want to use `stat` on the containing directory.

You're going to want to take a look at your systems definition of the `stat` function. [Here](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/fs/stat.c.html) is one example of the stat function implementation. Its definitely not as easy as just calling `stat`. But if you study this source and follow links in it, you'll get an idea of how it works.

Unfortunately I'm sane enough to not study the source, and am unsure if it can be done with just combinations of `open` and `read`. My guess is no, though (just a guess)